# Longest path in Kn

Tags: graph-theory

Given some $K_n$ and some $n\in N$, how can i find the longest path that exists in an undirected graph (not as a general term)?

Suppose $K_7$.

Repeted Verticies, no repeted edges

Comment: What properties do you need the path to have?

Comment: Usually... when we talk about a *path*, we require certain things... like no repeated vertices and no repeated edges, etc... *Surely* if we were to be having no repeated vertices and we were asking about a longest path in $K_n$ you should be able to argue why it will look a certain way and have a certain number of vertices and edges.  Perhaps you are just confusing yourself because of all of the extra edges involved... how about if we were to ask the same question about $C_n$ instead?  A cycle with $n$ vertices.  Can you answer the question for that graph?  Can you see why the answer is same?

Comment: This question is more about reading comprehension than anything else...

Comment: I think that in my question there is repeted V .. im soryy i tought it too trivial

Answer (score 2):

If $n\le 2$ then the paths in $K_n$ are trivial. If $n\ge 3$ is odd then each vertex of $K_n$ has even degree, so $K_n$ has a closed Eulerian path. If $n\ge 3$ is even then each vertex $v$ of $K_n$ has odd degree, so if $v$ is not an endpoint of the path then at least one edge  of the path does not belong to $n$. On the other hand, a path, meeting each its endpoints $n-1$ times  and each other vertex of $K_n$ $n-2$ times exists. Indeed, pick an arbitrary perfect matching in $K_n$ and remove from $K_n$ all but one edge $e$ of the matching. Then the residual graph is connected, and each its vertex but endpoints of $e$ has even degree. So the residual graph admits an open Eulerian path.

Comment: About eulerian i forgot,but the other n-1 n-2 didnt know , thank you!